# Unable to post form data using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and i am using nextjs,Right now i am trying to Post Form data But Unable to get any response(even anything in console.log),I tried with following code in index.js but nothing works,Thank you in advance

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Link from 'next/link'
import Script from 'next/script'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from "axios";

//const Home: NextPage = () => {
const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    job: ""
  });
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log('Om Success')
    const value = e.target.value;
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Om Success");
    const userData = {
      name: state.name,
      job: state.job
    };
    axios.post("https://xxxxxxx.com/api/users", userData).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="name">
          Name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={state.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="job">
          Job
          <input
            type="text"
            name="job"
            value={state.job}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: @Titus no i did, just forget to type/paste here

Comment: Right click page, choose "Inspect" and go to the "Network" tab and then click the submit button. See if it's actually making the request and what response is received.

Comment: if "Om Success" not printing then try changining onSubmit={handleSubmit} to onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}

Comment: you might want to add this header when you are sending an object with a post method in axios : headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",},

Comment: Also, something very simple that we all forget from time to time: make sure your file is saved, and that your project is running :)

Comment: It seems your code is working fine but some issues with the API or Server may be CORS issue. I tried this URL `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` with your code 
and it is working fine.

Comment: @AtulKumar: Kindly please tell me which type of api should create ? means what is wrong with Api ?

Comment: @amit you can add after then `.catch(error => { console.log(error)})` to know what error is coming.

Comment: @amit did you try looking in the Network tab like I suggested? If you are getting an error response (such as a CORS issue), you'll see it in the Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

you can post axios data by using FormData() like:

```
const formData= new FormData();
```

And then add the fields to the form you want to send:

```
formData.append('name', state.name);
formData.append('job', state.job);

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "your url",
  data: formData,
}).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
```