# AxiosError: Network Error showing in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, next.js, axios

I am working with Reactjs and i am using Nextjs,I am trying to Post data with axios
But Data is inserting "NULL" values,Where i am wrong ?
Here is my code in nextjs

```
const userData = {
     name: state.name,  
      job: state.job
};
axios.post("https://diggdevelopment.com/openc/api/testinfo", userData).then((response) => {
        alert(response);
      });
```

Here is my code in php

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$name=$_POST['name'];
$job=$_POST['job'];
$data = array(
       'name'=>$name,
        'job'=>$job
       );
$this->db->insert('test',$data);
```

Comment: Put the await before axios.post, may be your call is taking time.

Comment: @ShahzadKhan Please explain your point sir, didn't understand

Comment: He said you should make it this way: `let response = await axios.post("https://diggdevelopment.com/openc/api/testinfo", userData);` then `alert(response);`

Comment: hard to say with such a small sample but i suspect your state.name or state.job is null. Check what axios i actually posting. otherwise there is a problem on the receiving end

Comment: yeah, like it should be `this.state.name`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed why tough? using the promise with .then should suffice

Comment: @IbrahimHammed: I tried with static values for testing but that time i got same error

Comment: Check your network tab for the request body. Also, check on your backend by var_dump($_POST); Also, What does this line stand for? `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);`? Taking raw input? Do not assign it to $_POST. Instead assign it to some other variable.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi : some other variable ? means like "$data=$_POST; " ?

Comment: No `$data= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);`

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi still getting same error

Comment: What does your request body show from network? And what does var_dump($data) show?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi how can i see ? means i just use form from frontend so how can i get data/result/response of api ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249506/discussion-between-sachin-bahukhandi-and-amit).

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398973/unable-to-post-form-data-using-reactjs/74411805#74411805

Answer (score 0):

```
const userData = JSON.stringify({ 
     name: state.name,  
      job: state.job
});  

axios.post("https://diggdevelopment.com/openc/api/testinfo", userData).then((response) => {
        alert(response);
      });
```

Comment: @amit should be JSON.stringify